# Sending data to PowerFlow from ASP.Net Core App

Tags: asp.net-core, power-automate

I am trying to post data to Power Automate HTTP Request trigger, but i just get all properties with Null values. I dont know what i am missing?

It is requeried to set "Content-Type":"application/json".
(blog post referecne: https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/call-flow-restapi/ )

My .Net corre app code is:

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();    
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, order);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<String>();
```

[http post data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QTKZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test it in my side, you can refer to my power-automate flow and my .net code below:

My flow shown as:
[image]

And my code shown as below:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var postData = "{\"name\": \"Hury\",\"email\": \"test@xxx.com\"}";
            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = client.PostAsync("your http request trigger url", httpContent);

            Console.WriteLine(response.Result);
        }
    }
}
```

After running this code, we can see the properties are post success from the request in the running history.
[image]